# How to use MAMP PHP on macOS big Sur

Tags: php, mamp, mamp-pro, macos-big-sur, php-7.4

I updated the to *MacOS Big Sur* and then switched to *MAMP Pro 6.3* from MAMP 4.x.

`which php` commands results the

> usr/php/bin/

I updated the path using following.
`vim ~/.bash_profile`

> export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.12/bin:$PATH export
> PATH="$HOME/.yarn/bin:$HOME/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/.bin:$PATH"

Press esc and then
`:wq`

`source ~/.bash_profile`

Now when I do `which php` it shows **MAMP's php7.4.12** but if close and re-open the terminal, it again says

> usr/php/bin

Btw, PHP 7.4.12 is set as Default version in MAMP Pro from PHP settings in MAMP Pro.

**Versoins**

- macOS Big Sur version 11.1
- MAMAP 6.3

Comment: SOLUTION:

Mac Big Sur uses "zsh" Oh-my-zosh for terminal. so, I did the following.

1. open terminal.

2. check if you have .zshrc file in your profile path (/Users/yourProfileName)

3. if you don't have .zshrc file, create one using (~  touch .zshrc) commamd.

4. add these lines: 
export MAMP_PHP=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.12/bin
export PATH="$MAMP_PHP:$PATH"

5. save the file. close the terminal and reopen it. Now run "which php" .

Comment: Question: I'm considering upgrading to Big Sur too. Was the upgrade of MAMP 4.x to 6 necessary due to the MAC being updated to Big Sur? If so, which MAC OS did you upgrade from where MAMP 4.x was working ok? Or did MAMP PRO 4.x work ok on Big Sur and you just wanted to go to 6?

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using MAMP PRO 6.x you can enable `Activate command line shortcuts for the selected PHP version, pear & pecl` within the MAMP PHP settings. This will add aliases to your .profile file. If this does not work right away find the .zshrc file if you have it and add `source ~/.profile;` within it.

Answer (score 2):

1. - Open a terminal.
2. - edit this file:

```
nano .zshrc
```

3. - add these two lines:

```
export MAMP_PHP=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.12/bin 
export PATH="$MAMP_PHP:$PATH"
```

NOTE: if you want another version, replace php7.4.12 for the version you want.

4. - Save the changes o  file and then close the terminal and reopen it.
5. - Now run "which php" and you will see the desire version of Php.